# Can we collpase comment section on disqus plugin?

Tags: wordpress, disqus

I have number of comments on my page , so that purpose need to hide all comments. So can any one suggest me best way to collapse/exapand comment section.
[image: U Can see Attachmet].

Comment: please help me?

Comment: jQuery toggle()

Comment: @Beneris can you tell me briefly.

Comment: Give me your HTML structure I will write JS code for it.

Comment: @Beneris I added Image for clarification.I used disqus comment system for showing comments. Now my question is , is there any way to collapse those comments by default. thanks

Comment: @G Naresh, I need actual HTML code ;) can you add it,in questions or jsfiddle link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.toggle-target` is a element which height will be changed
`.toggle-init` is element on which you click when you want toggle a block

```
<script>
    /* Hide element first */
    $('.toggle-target').hide();

    /* Toggle element height on init click */
    $('.toggle-init').on('click', function(){
        $('.toggle-target').slideToggle();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Please improve your answer by adding some explanation to it.